# Historical quotation search: Equations/formulae in (Latin?) prose, before modern symbolic notation

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, notation

I have been trying, without success, to find a vaguely-remembered quotation: the quadratic equation (or perhaps the quadratic formula), given in (Latin?) prose, along lines like “Consider that quantity, which, when multiplied by itself and under multiplication by the first constant, …”

The purpose is just to contrast with the clarity and compactness of modern algebraic notation — so it doesn’t need to be the quadratic equation or formula, and it doesn’t need to be in Latin; any similar historical quotation to illustrate the point would do.

(Two relevant meta threads: [Are history of maths questions acceptable?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/394/is-there-a-consensus-on-whether-history-of-mathematics-questions-are-acceptable), and [Area 51 proposal: history of science and maths](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1496/area-51-proposal-history-of-science-and-mathematics).  Also, [this question as a sample question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/history-of-science-and-mathematics/65580#65580) on that area 51 proposal.)

Comment: [This discussion](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/first-use-of-bernoullis-inequality-and-its-name) has links showing the lengths it took Sluse (1668), Barrow (1670), and Bernoulli (1689) to express  $(1+x)^n\geqslant 1+nx$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was quite normal before the invention of the modern notation. You can pretty much take any text from the 16th century. Let me give you a somewhat well known example from [Stifel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Stifel)'s "Arithmetica integra", 1544, p. 240:

> Primo. A numero radicum incipe, eumque dimidiatum, loco eius pone
>   dimidium illius, quod in loco suo stet, donec consumata sit tota
>   operatio.

which loosely translates to (my translation)

> First. Start with the root number, half it, and put the half in the
>   place, where it should remain, until the whole operation is performed.

so in formulas that would be $$\frac{x}{2}$$ which is a lot shorter. He goes on to explain how to solve quadratic equations in general and even gives a nice Mnemonic to remember how it works: AMASIAS. Here is a picture of the whole passage:[image]

I think even Descartes used quite long sentences to explain formulas.

Comment: I object to the last sentence: Descartes is amazingly modern. You can read *The Geometry* as easily as any modern textbook.

Comment: @abx:  Really?  Check out p. 22 on "the question begun by Euclid", which is awfully hard to understand, despite being advertised by Descartes as a major success of his.  https://ia600200.us.archive.org/19/items/geometryofrene00desc/geometryofrene00desc.pdf

Comment: @abx: You are right: In many places Descartes uses formulae in a way similar to the way we would today.

Comment: As to the invention of the modern notation, it is worth recalling that it was initially the result of a natural shortening process of the above mentioned sentences, by brachylogies and shorthands also used elsewhere in writing. For instance, the  symbol  ${\bf +}$ comes from the letter "t" in  "et" after  atrophy of "e". The symbol ${\bf \sqrt{}} $ is  a lowercase ${\bf r}$ for $root$, and so on.

Comment: @PietroMajer: that’s fascinating!  Can you suggest any good sources for seeing the intermediate stages?  Or, even better, any articles about this transition?

Comment: :) A wonderful classic is Florian Cajori's "A History of Mathematical Notation", https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp . I don't know of more recent works; Wikipedia has a nice article with references.

Comment: PS: of course $\sqrt{}$ as "r" should stand for the latin "radix" not "root"... (Anyway, "radix" and "root"  share the same  Indo-European root. 

Forgive the following miserable pun: the root of root is the square root I guess)

Comment: If you look up the $\sqrt{}$ symbol in Cajori's book, you will see that it is **not** derived from an **r**.  Somewhere on MO there is a fuller account of this.

Comment: Regarding the previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/412718), one such account is found in user112109's [answer to "What is the history of $\sqrt{}$"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/121214)

Answer (score 5):

A better known figure than the 16th century Stifel is the 17th century Pierre de Fermat who still used notation that was not fully symbolic.  Thus, in his work anticipating the calculus, he used the terms *aequalitat* and *adaequalitat* rather than the familiar equality symbol. An example may be found in section 8.8 of [this text](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/POSC_a_00101).